# Correct way of writing Selenium Unittests in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium, python-unittest

I have the following scenario:

```
Load Page A
Check if Element_A exists in Page A
Click Button_A
On Clicking Button_A, Page B is loaded
Check if Element_B exists in Page B and Click Button_B
and so on...
```

I have written my code like this:

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class MyWebsiteTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def test_element_a_in_page_a(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(PAGE_A)
        element = driver.get_element_by_id("element_a")
        self.assertIsNotNone(element,"Oops.")

    def load_page_b_if_previous_function_is_true(self):
        #WHAT DO I DO HERE?
        #I Need to run this function given test_element_a_in_page_a succeeds.

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

How do I do this?
How do I write `load_page_b_if_element_a_in_page_a`?

If I write the entire flow of tests in ONE function, then I can achieve it easily, but how do I do seperation of concerns? How do I divide the tasks into different functions without making firefox open multiple times?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unit tests are independent from each other by design. The ordering can be changed, but they shouldn't depend on each other's results.

In your case, you need to put `load_page_b_if_previous_function_is_true` inside `test_element_a_in_page_a`.

In general, you will need to write a single test function for each Selenium scenario. You cannot split actions which depend on each other into several test cases.